# Filter/get items by date

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

Database model:

```
class Expense(Base):
    __tablename__ = "expenses"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique = True, index=True)
    item = Column(String, index=True)
    price = Column(String, index=True)
    currency = Column(String, index=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=date.today())
```

Using SQLAlchemy I want to get all items that had been added today.

I tried :

```
today = date.today()
res = db.query(Expense).filter(Expense.created_at == today).all()
```

But `date.today()` returns `2022-09-16` and `Expense.created_at` is `2022-09-16 00:00:00`. Also I tried to store `created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now())` and query like:

```
today = datetime.now().day
res = db.query(Expense).filter(Expense.created_at.day == today).all()
```

But it returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem: the first one is to use between in order to filter for some date, as your column is `DateTime`, so it will compare the exact date and time.

Here is an example:

```py
today = datetime.now()
start = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
end = today.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)
res = db.Query(Expense).filter(Expense.created_at.between(start, end)).all()
```

The second way is to use SQLAlchemy layer over DB built-in functions. There is a built-in function `date` that gets the date of DateTime field. Here is an example:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
today = datetime.now().date()
res = db.Query(Expense).filter(func.date(Expense.created_at) == today).all()
```

Also, I see that you've made a small mistake in setting up one column:

```
created_at = Column(DateTime, default=date.today())
```

This means that every time you don't give the `created_at` column to the model, created_at will be the date of when the process started, as you've called function `today()`.

Default expects to receive callable, not function, so it should look like this:

```
created_at = Column(DateTime, default=date.today)
```

This way, when the default is needed, it will call function `date.today` every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second one is great for me!

Comment: Also, maybe you can advise me, is it correct to use ```res = db.Query(Expense).filter(func.date(and_(Expense.created_at) >= <some date>),(Expense.created_at) <= <some date>)).all()```. Because version with ```between``` is unclear for me, to tell the truth :)

Comment: You don't need `and_` as `filter` function is using and by default. I used previously something like this:
`db.Query(Expense).filter(func.date(Expense.created_at) >= <some date>, func.date(Expense.created_at) <= <some date>).all()`
But `between` do same and takes less characters to write :)